# Trouble copying and renaming an element by id

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getelementbyid, clonenode

Edited to show all code for clarity. The issue I am running into now is keeping the ui input class when copying the field as the way I cloned it before kept the formatting, but was not copying in a way that I was able to properly refactor the id when cloning. It is asking me to provide more details but that is about it I think. Oh, I also need to add a break at the end of each addition for proper formatting, but I just haven't gotten around to it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var ct= 0;
</script>


<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/template" id="claim_field">
    <div class="ui input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Claim #" id="claim1">
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="sku_field">
    <div class="ui input" id=cpsku>
        <input type="text" placeholder="SKU" id="sku1">
    </div>
    <br>
</script>

<div id="form">
    <div type ="number" id= "requests"> </div>
    <div class="ui input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Claim #" id="claim0">
</div>
<div class="ui input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="SKU" id="sku0">
</div>
<br>
</div>
<div id="controls">
<button onclick="addRow()" class="ui button">
Add request
</button>
<br><br><br>
<button onclick="submit()" class="ui button">
Submit
</button>
</div>
<script>
function addRow(){
  var start=document.getElementById('form');
  ct+=1;
  
  var clm= document.getElementById('claim0');
  //window.alert(clm);
  var cclone=clm.cloneNode(true);
  var sk= document.getElementById('sku0');
  var sclone=sk.cloneNode(true);
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  
  


    cclone.id= "claim"+(ct.toString());
    //window.alert(cclone.id);
    //window.alert(cclone.innerHTML);
    sclone.id= "sku"+(ct.toString());
    //window.alert(sclone.id);
    //window.alert('gets here');

  
  e.appendChild(cclone);
  e.appendChild(sclone);
  start.appendChild(e);
  //start.appendChild(<br>);
}

function submit(){
      var pairs =[]; // this will contain all the claim #s and skus at the end
      var i;
      //window.alert('value of ct is currently '+ct);
      for(i=0; i< ct;i++){
        //window.alert('ct is still '+ct);
        //window.alert('I is currently '+i);
        var req= [];
        var bit = 'claim'+(i.toString());
        var bot = 'sku'+(i.toString());
        window.alert('currently searching for row '+bit);
        window.alert('claim'+(i+1).toString()+' is '+document.getElementById(bit).value);
        window.alert('sku'+(i+1).toString()+' is '+document.getElementById(bot).value);
      }
  }


</script>

</head>
</html>
```

Comment: You are changing the id of the cloned `<script>` element, not the div inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're using the wrong `id` to fetch the input box:

```
var clm= document.getElementById('claim_field');
```

Note that `claim_field` is the `id` you've given your `script` tag.

Try this instead:

```
var clm= document.getElementById('claim1');
```

Comment: I see... Though, the issue I run into then is it's losing the ui input formatting that the original div had.

Comment: It's clear from your example that you're not posting all of your code.  The variable `ct` is referenced but never defined, and the element with the ID `form` is never defined.  You'd do better to post a working code example.  Chances are, if you're not getting the same style for the cloned input you're appending, you're probably not appending it to the same parent as the other input.  Something like `clm.parent.appendChild(cclone)` may do the trick.

Comment: Apologies, I edited the post to include all the code.